# vba array - handle conditions outside the preserved dimension of an array

Tags: arrays, vba, counter

[image]I would like to loop through my table, store values into array LotN() (in the picture there were 2 individual sample data sets, to illustrate that I may encounter different number of unique lot numbers) (and the screen cap was an illustration only.  Data were actually stored in an 2D array A1()).

```
candidate = "blah"     

' loop through records, add to arrays  (skip adding duplicated values with the function IsInArray = false)       
For i = 2 To LR
    If .Cells(i, 5).Value = candidate And IsInArray(.Cells(i, 2).Value, lotN) = False Then
        q = q + 1
        lotN(q) = .Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If
Next i
        
Debug.Print "q = " & q ' try to know how many records were thrown into the arrays
        
ReDim Preserve lotN(1 To q)
```

Usually q will be equal to 1 to 3 for my data, but I have to prepare for q up to 6, for the procedures below.  The next step I needed was to count the number of elements in another array A1() matching each of the elements in LotN().

```
' use counter to check the number of data pieces from another array A1() matching the elements within the array LotN()
For k = 1 To r
    If A1(k, 2) = lotN(1) And lotN(1) <> "" Then
        c = c + 1
    End If
    If A1(k, 2) = lotN(2) And lotN(2) <> "" Then
        d = d + 1
    End If
    If A1(k, 2) = lotN(3) And lotN(3) <> "" Then ' with q = 2, the code stopped at this line with error "script out of range"
        e = e + 1
    End If
    If A1(k, 2) = lotN(4) And lotN(4) <> "" Then
        f = f + 1
    End If
    If A1(k, 2) = lotN(5) And lotN(5) <> "" Then
        g = g + 1
    End If
    If A1(k, 2) = lotN(6) And lotN(6) <> "" Then
        h = h + 1
    End If
    
Next k
```

I want to create counters (c, d, e, f, g, h in the lines above) for each of the elements in the array.  Since I am not sure how exactly q will be equal to, my attempt was to use lotN (position of element in this array) <> "" to allow increment of counters.  That doesn't work, however.  With q = 2, lines at or below the indicated will still cause an error "Script out of range".

How can I handle this error?

Comment: Please, read this: [Subscript out of range (Error 9)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/subscript-out-of-range-error-9)

Comment: You can *handle* the error, but you shouldn't. You should not make it in the first place. You know your `UBound(lotN)`. So don't go into the branches that involve an index greater than that.

Comment: Why don't you use a `Dictionary` to store your values? I see that you want to store unique values from your table. Using `If Not Dict.Exists(cell.value) Then Dict.Add cell.value, 1` for example

Comment: @Damian thanks for your advice.  That's one of the modification I would do later on.  I was thinking of using collection or dictionary instead of an array.

Comment: I would even use class objects... for every ID get a new dictionary which will increase it's value everytime it matches with the A1 array... but I can't grasp the end goal of your code...

Comment: @Damian I added a screen cap of my data set samples.  My proximal goal was to modify the values of column G.  Like rows 12 to 23 in the picture, I eventually will make the values become 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 instead of 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2 (by adding the number of records of PREVIOUS LOT to each new record)

Comment: @JohnLiu that enumeration is for each ID in column B, right? You want each ID to start from 1 and increase everytime it's found again.

Comment: @Damian yes you're right.  In data set 2, since there were 3 records with "60400D", I need the levels on column G with lot = "60400" to be topped up with 3 i.e. Lv = Lv + 3.  And since 4 records were found with "73611", I need the levels with lot "85321" be added with 3, 3, 4 i.e. Lv = Lv + 3 + 3 + 4

Comment: please also note that the screen cap was an illustration only.  The data were actually stored in an array A1().

Comment: @JohnLiu I am a bit slow this morning, can you post a screenshot with your desired output? I can't wrap my mind around your last comment.

Comment: @Damian and all.  I think I may had made too much edits and cannot attach another screen cap at the moment.  Eventually I would like values on column G to be changed FROM (case 1) 1,2,3,1,2,3 TO 1,2,3,4,5,6 and FROM (case 2) 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2 TO 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.  Note that these values were actually stored in an array A1().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work you will need the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` library under tools-References.

This is the code commented:

```
Option Explicit
Const Candidate As String = "blah"
Sub Test()
    
    'Here we will store the Candidates to enum
    Dim Candidates As Dictionary: Set Candidates = LoadCandidates
    'Another dictionary to hold the candidates on the array
    Dim lotN As Dictionary: Set lotN = New Dictionary
    For K = 1 To r
        'If the value is in the Candidates Dictionary then
        If Candidates.Exists(A1(K, 2)) Then
            'If the Candidate is in the lotN already, add 1
            If lotN.Exists(A1(K, 2)) Then
                lotN(A1(K, 2)) = lotN(A1(K, 2)) + 1
            'If not, add the candidate to the lotN and equal it to 1
            Else
                lotN.Add A1(K, 2), 1
            End If
            'output the number of times the candidate has appeared
            A1(K, 7) = lotN(A1(K, 2))
        End If
    Next K


End Sub
Private Function LoadCandidates() As Dictionary
    
    Set LoadCandidates = New Dictionary
    For i = 2 To LR
        If Cells(i, 5) = Candidate And Not LoadCandidates.Exists(Cells(i, 2).Value) Then
            LoadCandidates.Add Cells(i, 2).Value, 1
        End If
    Next i

End
```

P.S.: Amend the code to fit your needs because you didn't post the whole code you need to reference the worksheet and workbook for the cells and give the A1 array...

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I think it is close to what I needed.  Let me fit it into my code and get back to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Since the size of your array is variable, I advise you to instead of looping through a set range, to loop through the array itself.

```
counter = 0

For Each itm in lotN
    counter = counter + 1
    
    If A1(counter, 2) = itm Then
        If counter = 1 Then
            c = c + 1
        ElseIf counter = 2 Then
            d = d + 1
        ElseIf counter = 3 Then
            e = e + 1
        ElseIf counter = 4 Then
            f = f + 1
        ElseIf counter = 5 Then
            g = g + 1
        ElseIf counter = 6 Then
            h = h + 1
        End If
    End If
Next itm
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am afraid I did not make my question clear enough (and I forgot that I can attach a screen cap for your reference).  Please see my edit with pic and see if you have any thoughts on it.